# Why are values in the console but not being displayed in the page?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Values are not displayed on page, but are displayed in console.log

```
//app.components.ts
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  posts: any[];
  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase){
    db.list('posts').valueChanges().subscribe(posts => {  this.posts = posts; console.log(this.posts); });

  }
}

//app.component.html

    <ul>
  <li *ngFor="let post of posts">
{{post.$value}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

//firebase

[image: that's my firebase]

[image: and here what I have]

Comment: just do {{post}}

Answer (score 0):

As @Peter Haddad mentioned you have to add `{{post}}` instead of `{{post.$value}}` on the list like this:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let post of posts">
{{post}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

More info about it:
https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#add-logic-to-loop-through-data

I hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let post of posts">
{{post}}
  </li>
</ul>
```